# JList - set allowed selection combinations

Tags: java, selection, combinations, jlist

I have a `JList` with 8 string items. The customer wants to have four possible selection combinations. The code example produces such list. I am partly accomplishing this in an ugly way with mouse listener.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Selections {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        items.add("11");
        items.add("21");
        items.add("31");
        items.add("41");
        items.add("12");
        items.add("22");
        items.add("32");
        items.add("42");

        final ArrayList<String> combinationOne = new ArrayList<String>();
        combinationOne.add("11");
        combinationOne.add("12");
        final ArrayList<String> combinationTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
        combinationTwo.add("21");
        combinationTwo.add("22");
        final ArrayList<String> combinationThree = new ArrayList<String>();
        combinationThree.add("31");
        combinationThree.add("32");
        final ArrayList<String> combinationFour = new ArrayList<String>();
        combinationFour.add("41");
        combinationFour.add("42");

        JList list = new JList(items.toArray());

        MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                JList eventList = (JList) mouseEvent.getSource();
                int index = eventList.locationToIndex(mouseEvent.getPoint());
                if (index >= -1) {
                    Object o = eventList.getModel().getElementAt(index);
                    System.out.println(o.toString());
                    if (combinationOne.contains(eventList.getSelectedValue())) {
                        eventList.addSelectionInterval(0, 0);
                        eventList.addSelectionInterval(4, 4);
                    } else if (combinationTwo.contains(eventList.getSelectedValue())) {
                        eventList.addSelectionInterval(1, 1);
                        eventList.addSelectionInterval(5, 5);
                    } else if(combinationThree.contains(eventList.getSelectedValue())) {
                        eventList.addSelectionInterval(2, 2);
                        eventList.addSelectionInterval(6, 6);
                    } else if (combinationFour.contains(eventList.getSelectedValue())) {
                        eventList.addSelectionInterval(3, 3);
                        eventList.addSelectionInterval(7, 7);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        list.addMouseListener(mouseListener);

        list.setSelectionMode(
            ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        // Set the default selection
        list.addSelectionInterval(0, 0);
        list.addSelectionInterval(4, 4);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(list));
    }
}
```

Here are some issues with this implementation:

1. The selection starts on mouse clicked, but the second selection happens after mouse released. This creates an impression for inconsistency.
2. You will also see that there is a short delay in the second item selection as it happens after mouse released.
3. There are borders set around the second selected item, which are not desired.
4. You can move between the items with arrow up/down, which is not handled.

Moreover, I do not like this implementation way as it is not a clean one.

I've tried with a `ListSelectionListener` but I couldn't avoid the selection event loop and it went to overflow.

Comment: If at a given point of time, you want to select two items in list from two apparent different sets in same list, then why cant you have two separate JList? You may synchronize the selections between them two.

Comment: Good point, but I will always become a different items configuration. So it may happen to have only two items and one combination, or 20 items and 3 combinations. It will be too hard to use different JList counts. Also, consider that the item sequence shall remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this without 4th point.

```
    class Selections{

    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> combinationOne = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> combinationTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> combinationThree = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> combinationFour = new ArrayList<String>();

    JList list = null;
    public Selections(){
        items.add("11");
        items.add("21");
        items.add("31");
        items.add("41");
        items.add("12");
        items.add("22");
        items.add("32");
        items.add("42");

        list = new JList(items.toArray());

        combinationOne.add("11");
        combinationOne.add("12");
        combinationTwo.add("21");
        combinationTwo.add("22");
        combinationThree.add("31");
        combinationThree.add("32");
        combinationFour.add("41");
        combinationFour.add("42");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Selectionsselections = new Selections();
        selections.runApp();

    }

    private void runApp() {
    MouseMotionListener mouseMotionListener = new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            JList eventList = (JList) e.getSource();
            addSelectionInterval(eventList);
        }
    };
        MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                JList eventList = (JList) mouseEvent.getSource();
                int index = eventList.locationToIndex(mouseEvent.getPoint());
                if (index >= -1) {
                    addSelectionInterval(eventList);
                }
            }
        };
        list.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        list.addMouseMotionListener(mouseMotionListener );
        list.setCellRenderer(getRenderer());
        list.setSelectionMode(
                ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        // Set the default selection
        list.addSelectionInterval(0, 0);
        list.addSelectionInterval(4, 4);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(list));
    }

    private void addSelectionInterval(JList eventList) {
        if (combinationOne.contains(eventList.getSelectedValue())) {
            eventList.addSelectionInterval(0, 0);
            eventList.addSelectionInterval(4, 4);
        } else if (combinationTwo.contains(eventList.getSelectedValue())) {
            eventList.addSelectionInterval(1, 1);
            eventList.addSelectionInterval(5, 5);
        } else if(combinationThree.contains(eventList.getSelectedValue())) {
            eventList.addSelectionInterval(2, 2);
            eventList.addSelectionInterval(6, 6);
        } else if (combinationFour.contains(eventList.getSelectedValue())) {
            eventList.addSelectionInterval(3, 3);
            eventList.addSelectionInterval(7, 7);
        }
    }

    private ListCellRenderer<? super String> getRenderer() {
        return new DefaultListCellRenderer(){
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,
                                                          Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
                                                          boolean cellHasFocus) {
                JLabel listCellRendererComponent = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected,cellHasFocus);
                listCellRendererComponent.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
                return listCellRendererComponent;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I fixed point 4 myself with: list.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "none"); and list.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "none"); .


Now remains the problem when the mouse have moved in the time between it is pressed and released.

Comment: Just updated the answer with your current problem. Added motion listener to handle that.

Comment: Works like a charm now!